Excel- Product cross reference to return amounts shipped vs received
I'm trying to create a tool that allows a data dump of shipping invoices from my company and invoices filed through the state. Then spit out a table where it's easy to see quantity variances.
I have a sheet for the table of variances and a sheet for our invoice data and a 3rd for the state's invoice list.
The complexity lies in the product naming conventions. Both include a lot of text descriptors of the product and some have unit amounts. Depending on the product, there may be 2 or 3 words that match 100%.
My INDEX(MATCH) works to retrieve the shipped amounts based on one of the words in the product description (using wildcards), but relying on one word runs into duplication problems.
My XLOOKUP only pulled the very top amount from the received/shipped.
When I add as second criteria to the Match, I always get #NA. (granted the second one is trying to read from the same cell as the first)
Here's my questions:
Is INDEX/MATCH my best bet?
If not, what would do the trick?
Why would my indexmatch work fine with one criteria but not two?
I'm not that proficient with VBA but if that's the direction I should, I'll probably follow-up here.
Thanks!

maybe try "Fuzzy Lookup Add-In for Excel" (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15011&) It generates a similarity score, but guidance on what to do with those scores may depend on more details of your circumstances.

How are you adding a second criteria to your INDEX/MATCH?
